# import django_filters in filers.py shows "Import "django_filters" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports"

Tags: python, django

I have tried looking for the solution in other threads but still stuck to the problem.

My python version is 3.9.5;
I reinstalled django to a lower version (it was 3.2.0, later installed 3.0)

```
      INSTALLED_APPS = [
      ...
      ...
     'django_filters',
    ]
```

**error**

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\anika tabassum era\appdata\local\programs\python\python
line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\users\anika tabassum era\appdata\local\programs\python\python
line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\DJPROJ\FINALS\DennisCRM\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\au in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\DJPROJ\FINALS\DennisCRM\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\manrver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "D:\DJPROJ\FINALS\DennisCRM\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\au in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "D:\DJPROJ\FINALS\DennisCRM\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\man
line 375, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "D:\DJPROJ\FINALS\DennisCRM\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\au in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\DJPROJ\FINALS\DennisCRM\env\lib\site-packages\django\__init__p
  File "D:\DJPROJ\FINALS\DennisCRM\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\reg populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "D:\DJPROJ\FINALS\DennisCRM\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\con
create
    import_module(entry)
  File "c:\users\anika tabassum era\appdata\local\programs\python\python    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlo
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_modul
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_r
  File "D:\DJPROJ\FINALS\DennisCRM\env\lib\site-packages\django_filters\
in <module>
  File "D:\DJPROJ\FINALS\DennisCRM\env\lib\site-packages\django_filters\, in <module>
    from django.utils import six
ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'django.utils' (D:\DJPROJ\FINsite-packages\django\utils\__init__.py)
```

installed as `pip install django-filter`.
In my **filters.py** I am getting the line *import *django_filters** as yellow underlined and on hover shows **Import "django_filters" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports**

Can anyone please guide me through? Thanks.

Comment: cannot import name 'six' from 'django.utils' ? it's not `django_filters`!?

Comment: @MojixCoder I did have installed django-filters. But the error is unknown to me.